# Why do we use argument -i in rosdep install?

Tags: rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ROS2 and going through the tutorials [here](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Creating-A-Workspace/Creating-A-Workspace.html). I want to know why do we use the argument `-i` during `rosdep install`. I went through the man pages of `rosdep` and could not really understand why rosdep needs to ignore keys that are found to be catkin or ament packages. This is man page definition:

```
  -i, --ignore-packages-from-source, --ignore-src
                        Affects the 'check', 'install', and 'keys' verbs. If
                        specified then rosdep will ignore keys that are found
                        to be catkin or ament packages anywhere in the
                        ROS_PACKAGE_PATH, AMENT_PREFIX_PATH or in any of the
                        directories given by the --from-paths option.
```

What is the need to ignore the keys that are found to be catkin or ament packages anywhere in the path?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/404603/why-do-we-use-argument--i-in-rosdep-install?/) by [tsadarsh](https://answers.ros.org/users/70847/tsadarsh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2022-08-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> What is the need to ignore the keys that are found to be catkin or ament packages anywhere in the path?

no, that's not what `-i` is for/does.

`--ignore-packages-from-source` tells `rosdep` to consider dependencies which it can find locally, in your workspace, as fulfilled.

In other words: if there are 4 dependencies, and 3 are already present in your workspace, `rosdep` will only install the single remaining dependency *you don't have in your workspace*.

Example: `package.xml` of `pkg_c` states dependency on `pkg_a` and `pkg_b`. Your workspace contains `pkg_a`. `rosdep` will only install `pkg_b`. `pkg_a` will be built as part of your workspace.

The usage text mentions "catkin or ament packages" as those are the only two types of packages `rosdep` would be able to detect in your workspace. You could have 20 other packages there (NPM, Conan, plain CMake, etc), but unless they are either Catkin or Ament packages, `rosdep` wouldn't know.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2022-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1